# To validate an object I but don't repeat I can pass different Objects to the same method?

Tags: java, web-services, validation, jakarta-ee, constraints

I have a method to launch the verification of my object but not always is the same class object.
I use this block of code:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<typeClass>> violations = validator.validate(className);
    for (ConstraintViolation<typeClass> violation : violations) {
    logger.debug(violation.getMessage());
    output = violation.getMessage();
}
```

and I want to use it in a method but the *className* and *typeClass* are variable, then if I made a method with String for example:

```
public Response getValidations(String typeClass, String helloString) {
    //do the validation of the string
}
```

*helloString* is the name of the object but the type *String* of the object it depends on the first param I pass to the method.

Comment: Um.. are you looking for a way to "validate by example" and enforce at compile time that both of them have the same type?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov i'm trying to validate my classes with bean-validation. Every class have his own validations but i want to use the same method to all.

Comment: Won't `Validator` already do the validation of any class supported by its `ValidatorFactory`? There's no `validator.validate(class)`, there is `validator.validate(instance, groups...)`, which will totally suffice to _do the validaton of any object_.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov finally i found the answer, thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer, It was so easy that it pissed me off -_-

```
private String makeVerifications(Object instance, Validator validator) {
    String output = "";

    Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = validator.validate(instance);
    for (ConstraintViolation<Object> violation : violations) {
        logger.debug(violation.getMessage());
        output += System.getProperty("line.separator") + violation.getMessage();
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: `violations.stream().map(ConstraintViolation::getMessage).collect(Collectors.joining(System.getProperty("line.separator"));`